# Range query on indexed property

Tags: indexing, neo4j, range

Is there a maximum limit on the range size while querying a range of indexed property?

To clarify, I have a timestamp property in milliseconds which is indexed and I am trying to get all the events that happened in a month. So I have a query like this

```
Match (e:Event)-[R:type{'has metadata'}]-> (S:EventMetaData) where e.type=~".*ELec.*" AND e.timestamp IN RANGE (1480550400000,1483228740000)  return S.Location, sum(e.value) as sumV  order by  sumV DESC
```

But I got the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Cannot index an collection of size 2678340001
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.commands.expressions.IndexedInclusiveLongRange.length(IndexedInclusiveLongRange.scala:51)
at scala.collection.SeqLike$class.size(SeqLike.scala:106)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.commands.expressions.IndexedInclusiveLongRange.size(IndexedInclusiveLongRange.scala:30)
at scala.collection.mutable.Builder$class.sizeHint(Builder.scala:69)
at scala.collection.mutable.SetBuilder.sizeHint(SetBuilder.scala:20)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.to(TraversableLike.scala:589)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.commands.expressions.IndexedInclusiveLongRange.to(IndexedInclusiveLongRange.scala:30)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toSet(TraversableOnce.scala:304)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.commands.expressions.IndexedInclusiveLongRange.toSet(IndexedInclusiveLongRange.scala:30)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.commands.indexQuery$.apply(indexQuery.scala:46)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.NodeIndexSeekPipe.internalCreateResults(NodeIndexSeekPipe.scala:48)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.Pipe$class.createResults(Pipe.scala:51)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.NodeIndexSeekPipe.createResults(NodeIndexSeekPipe.scala:29)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:79)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:79)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:79)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:79)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:79)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:79)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:79)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.executionplan.DefaultExecutionResultBuilderFactory$ExecutionWorkflowBuilder.createResults(DefaultExecutionResultBuilderFactory.scala:95)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.executionplan.DefaultExecutionResultBuilderFactory$ExecutionWorkflowBuilder.build(DefaultExecutionResultBuilderFactory.scala:73)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.BuildInterpretedExecutionPlan$$anonfun$getExecutionPlanFunction$1.apply(BuildInterpretedExecutionPlan.scala:99)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.BuildInterpretedExecutionPlan$$anonfun$getExecutionPlanFunction$1.apply(BuildInterpretedExecutionPlan.scala:83)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v3_2.BuildInterpretedExecutionPlan$$anon$1.run(BuildInterpretedExecutionPlan.scala:54)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.v3_2.Compatibility$ExecutionPlanWrapper$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Compatibility.scala:96)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.v3_2.Compatibility$ExecutionPlanWrapper$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Compatibility.scala:94)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.v3_2.exceptionHandler$runSafely$.apply(exceptionHandler.scala:84)
at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.v3_2.Compatibility$ExecutionPlanWrapper.run(Compatibility.scala:94)
```

It's a kind of weird that neo4j tries to allocate collection of size endRange-startRange as the error states. I know I can work around that by storing the timestamp in hours/days but I am still curious to know why the range query performance on indexed properties is slow in neo4j and if there's a maximum allowed range size?

P.S. I increased both neo4j heap and page caching size but still having slow performance with the range queries on indexed properties

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to use a **very** inefficient technique (even if it worked) to test the range, since the `RANGE` function is defined to generate a collection of `N+1` values (where `N` is the difference between the upper and lower bounds of the range), and the `IN` operation would make a comparison against *every item* in the collection (in the worst case).

You should change your query slightly to make just 2 numeric comparisons per row:

```
MATCH (e:Event)-[R:type{'has metadata'}]-> (S:EventMetaData)
WHERE e.type=~".*ELec.*" AND 1480550400000 <= e.timestamp <= 1483228740000
RETURN S.Location, sum(e.value) AS sumV
ORDER BY  sumV DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually, this was the first version of my query, I was using "<" and ">" in my query before using Range and yes it has better performance. But the point is that I am trying to study the impact of indexing on query performance and using the ">" and "<" implies not using the index based on Query tuning tip#1 here https://neo4j.com/blog/neo4j-2-2-query-tuning/  So, I had to switch to the "Range" to be able to use the index. I am currently wondering if there is a way to use indexing in a Range query in efficient way?